# jQuery plugin options is showing `not defined`

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I am developing a jquery plugin.The plugin has some options which can be selected by users.If not selected they stay defaults.The problem is i am not getting options using the jquery $.extend method

### My codes are given below

```
    $.fn.ajaxload = function( options ){
    var defaults = {
        ajaxload : true,
        loadType : 'inline', // 3 options - inline,inpage,inmodal
        screenOverlay : true,
        prefferedWrap : '.ajax-content-wrap',
        ajaxClose : '.ajax-close'
    }, options = $.extend(defaults, options || {});

    }

    var ajaxLoad = $(this),
        closeBtn = options.ajaxClose;
```

If i console.log the `closeBtn` in console it comes : `Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined`

Can anyone help?

Comment: the function `ajaxload` is closed before `var ajaxLoad`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8m59sfu8/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny , If i need the variable out of the closure?